# npm install failed with Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink '\node_modules'

Tags: node.js, angularjs, windows-10, npm-install

I try to run "npm install" command in CMD ["node_modules" is inside C drive] but installation failing with below error.

```
OS :Windows 10.

Node JS version: 6.9.0.
```

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink.

Goal: To run AngularJs project.

CMD command

```
npm install -- no optional;
```

> PS C:\Users\arunk\Work\Workspaces\workspace-2\brainbox-frontend-angular> npm install --no-optional
>
> ```
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\arunk\Work\Workspaces\workspace-2\brainbox-frontend-angular\node_modules\.staging\typescript-5afdc8eb\lib\tsc.js
> npm ERR! code EPERM
> npm ERR! errno -4048
> npm ERR! syscall unlink
> npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\arunk\Work\Workspaces\workspace-2\brainbox-frontend-angular\node_modules\.staging\typescript-5afdc8eb\lib\tsc.js'
> npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\arunk\Work\Workspaces\workspace-2\brainbox-frontend-angular\node_modules\.staging\typescript-5afdc8eb\lib\tsc.js']
> {
> npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink ' +
> npm ERR!     "'C:\\Users\\arunk\\Work\\Workspaces\\workspace-2\\brainbox-frontend-angular\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-5afdc8eb\\lib\\tsc.js'",
> npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
> npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
> npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
> npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\arunk\\Work\\Workspaces\\workspace-2\\brainbox-frontend-angular\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-5afdc8eb\\lib\\tsc.js'
> npm ERR! }
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
> npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
> npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
> npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
> npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\arunk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-22T19_01_22_659Z-debug.log
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Like you I have wasted much time trying to get 'npm install' to install Angular projects from its 'project.json' file and received similar error messages that are unhelpful; Recently I installed 'yarn' and this does a much better job of populating the 'node_modules' folder and it also generates more useful error and warning messages in the process.

Try the following steps:

1. Install 'Yarn' - go to it's website and download the installer for your operating system.
2. Got to your project directory (the one containing 'project.json')
3. enter the command 'yarn' and wait. This will perform the same function
   as 'npm install', however it will generate fewer messages but the ones
   it does will be more pertinent.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Please try following steps:

1. check your antivirus status is enable or disable
2. disable your antivirus during the installation.

I hope this helps. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and tried a lot of different things. This solved my problem:

```
1 - Uninstall NodeJs
2 - Delete folders 'npm' and 'npm-cache' from AppData/Roaming
3 - Deactivate firewall and all antivirus (including Windows Defender)
4 - Reboot the system
5 - Open command prompt as administrator and execute 'npm install'
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using yarn to install axios and got the same error, but I figured out that this error is not peculiar to axios since the same thing happens with all other packages.

Killing all running node process worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a problem with the file system.

Check your C drive with the windows verification tool (right click on the C: -> Properties -> Tools -> Check). Repair the errors if it's needed.

It worked for me. I write here this solution for people (like me) with similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem can also happen if you try to uninstall a dependency while in another terminal window you're using

```
ng serve
```

Simply stop that operation and only then you can uninstall it.