# encountering installation error for vue-cli npm

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, npm-install

I cloned one of my repo to my device and i get this error. I have yet to find a solution for this error that I am getting. I hope this may be resolved. Cheers!

[image]

Comment: i dont see any issue with vue or npm? But i guess it is in *I cloned*.

Comment: Try these answers, might be a problem with npm cache or filesystem permissions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263640/npm-install-failed-with-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-unlink-node-mod

Comment: Having this issue from time to time as well. Try closing all editors/similar stuff that might access the files and run it again. Sometimes the file is still in use and the CLI throws the error